# Run Python script in a custom Python folder

Tags: python

I have a problem running a python script on a system that doesn't have Python installed.  I know what you're thinking...but hear me out.

Some applications like C4D and Maya come with their own versions of Python.  Unfortunately, they often compile them incorrectly, so modules that should import on their version of Python (e.g. 2.6 for C4D) don't work at all.  I don't know why they do this, I've asked, but it appears to be due to a lack of knowledge on their part.

To use a module that won't import, you have to use a separate python installation.  But I don't want to force users to install python, so I include my own python folder (2.7.6) with the modules I want to use inside and launch my script inside my custom (non-installed) python folder like this:

```
cmd = [my_python_path, "-E", my_script.py]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, bufsize=...etc.
```

This works fine as long as Python 2.7.6 is actually installed on the system, but if it isn't installed, then it doesn't work.  My system above isn't targeting, or using the installed python.  In fact, I've moved the installed Python folder, and renamed it to make sure it isn't being used somehow, and my script works fine.  So I know it is executing with my python folder.

Question 1: Why won't the python.exe run inside my custom folder unless there is an installed version of python?  Is this because of some path variable?

Question 2: How can I make my python.exe work on systems, both Mac and Win, without Python officially installed?

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? What exactly happens? What error you get?

Comment: An error message pops up, depending on the platform, that says 'python.exe has stopped working'.  Then, if you install Python, it works fine.  Uninstall Python, and you get the message again.  Somehow the python.exe in the custom folder is looking for something that it can only find if Python is installed.  It can't be in the installed Python folder, because I've tried moving, renaming, etc. that folder and my script runs fine even if you delete the folder.  What is my python.exe file looking for?

Comment: Not sure. You might want to read this: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables Try setting up some of these variables, especially PYTHONHOME.

Comment: The "-E" in the args passed with subprocess.Popen makes Python ignore those variables.  I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just running Python.exe from custom folder doesn't tell it the specific location of many files and folders. These stuff are fixed in Windows as System Variables.

If you are copying the whole python folder, why not install python instead? It'll take same space too? Or if you really wan't to create executable use:-

1. Py2Exe for windows!
2. py2app from Mac!
3. Pyinstaller for both

I prefer py2exe.

Comment: Well, I'm not doing this for me, it is for software I distribute.  So I have been looking for the best way for the end-users.  I just tried Pyinstaller, and it worked for Win, I'll give it a try for OSX now.  Thanks.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark a green tick for correct answer

Comment: BTW its hss2268 from freenode chat ere